# Lagrange interpolation for ellipse

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Consider the ellipse

$$\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{2} =1$$

The line integral $I$ of the ellipse in the first quadrant is

$$I=\int^2_0 \Big[ 1+(y'(x))^2 \Big]^{1/2} dx$$

Find the cubic polynomial $P_3(x)$ that interpolates y(x) in the first quadrant at $x=0, 1, \sqrt{2}, 2.$ We would then have

$$I \approx \int^2_0 \Big[ 1+(P'(x))^2 \Big]^{1/2}$$

Find the cubic polynomial $Q_3 (x)$ that interpolates $\sqrt{1+(P_3' (x)')^2}$ at these points. Hence estimate $I.$

**Attempt**

Rearranging $y=\sqrt{2 \left( 1- \frac{x^2}{4} \right)}$ we get

[image]

We will have the following Lagrange polynomial:

$$p_3(x) = y(x_0) \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_0 - x_1)(x_0-x_2) (x_0-x_3)}+y(x_1) \frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_1 - x_0)(x_1-x_2) (x_1-x_3)} +y(x_2) \frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_3)}{(x_2 - x_0)(x_2-x_1) (x_2-x_3)} + y(x_3) \frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_3 - x_0)(x_3-x_1) (x_3-x_2)}$$

But when I substitute the numbers in, the resulting polynomial looks extremely messy so I am not sure if I am on the right track. And when we have this polynomial how do we exactly need to proceed to find $Q_3 (x)$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks ugly $\left(2+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right) (x-2) \left(\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \left(\sqrt{3}-2\right) x^2+\left(-2 \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}+1\right) x+2 \sqrt{2}-3\right)$

Comment: No man, I think it is beautiful!

Comment: @Moo Yes, this is exactly what I have. So, how do we use this for finding $Q_3(x)$ and estimating $I$?

Comment: @Moo So, I found the derivative $P'_3(x)$ to be $((2+\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}})(\sqrt{2}-1)(\sqrt{3}-2))(3x^2-4x)+ \sqrt{6}-2 \sqrt{3} + 1.$ So once I plug this into $I = \int^2_0 \Big[ 1+ (p'(x))^2 \Big]^{1/2}$ I get $I$. Right? So what exactly would be the polynomial $Q_3 (x)$ that they are asking for?

Comment: Are you now doing some numerical integration to solve that integral?

Comment: @Moo The question is about estimating the integral using interpolation, so I found $p(x)$ that interpolates $y(x).$ In the second part they ask for $Q_3(x)$ that interpolates the integrand $\sqrt{1+(P'_3)^2}$ over those four points, and hence estimate $I$. So does that mean I need to repeat the whole process again, but this time with $y=\sqrt{1+(P'_3)^2}$?